# Perl Regexp with an option

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to parse this string and the number between /TN and ending forward /.  Also, if there is a /REF I need to grab the REF # as well. So it could be an either or situation.

Example String:

```
my $acis_string = 'EL41X/TN 333-3333 /DES TAT 313 223-2388 OE508-1-12-13/ORD R1244850301 /CD 02-03-15 /ZKMA 8001 T1ZF PNTCMINEDC0 PNTCMISOH00/SCS DQKUX /TN 333-3330, 6540/RTI 581 /LSO 248 340/REF 28/TGP 581 /ORD C1244888657/CD 02-12-16';
```

He was my base regexp:

```
push @matches, [$2, $1] while $acis_string =~ /\/TN (.*?)\/.*?(\/REF (\w+)\/)?/g;
```

Desired Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
      [
        n/a,
        '333-3333 '
      ],
      [
        28,
        '333-3330, 6540'
      ]
    ];
```

Note:
There could be many /TN / and /REF in the string.

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't understand what you are asking here. There is no question in your question. Please [edit] it to clarify what you want to know, or what is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
\/TN\s+([^\/]+)(?:(?!\/TN|\/REF).)*(?:\/REF\s+([^\/]+))?
```

See [RegEX DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uC6mV9/1)

**Explanation:**

- `\/TN\s+([^\/]+)` : Match characters other than `/` after `/TN` and put in capture group 1
- `(?:(?!\/TN|\/REF).)*` : Logic to match characters making sure there is no `/TN` or `/REF` in them
- `(?:\/REF\s+([^\/]+))?` : Optionally match characters other than `/` after `/REF` and put in capture group 2

Answer (score 1):

You can use `/TN` as a record separator and read the string with a filehandler:

```
my @res;
{
    my $ref;
    local $/='/TN ';
    open my $fh, '<', \$acis_string;
    <$fh>;
    while(<$fh>) {
        $ref = m#/REF ([^/]*[^/\s])# ? $1 : 'n/a';
        push @res, [$ref, m#^([^/]*[^/\s])#];
    }
    close $fh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `\/(TN[^\/]+)|\/(REF[^\/]+)`

## Explanation

- `\/` Escaped `/`
- `(TN[^\/]+)` Capture `TN` followed by things that aren't `/`
- `|` Or your other option